# Referencing any external java class from xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I am creating xsd files and converting java classes from those xsd files using JAXB. In the following example, ClassB was defined/declared in some jar file and I want to reference it in my xsd like this:

```
<complexType name="ClassA">
  <sequence>
    <element name="objB" type="ClassB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Is this allowed? What's the best way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  <xs:complexType name="ClassBType" abstract="true">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:class name="ClassB" implClass="fully.qualified.package.name.ClassB"/>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!--

  -->
  <xs:complexType name="ClassA">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ClassBType">
    .
    .
    Any optional <xs:attribute> elements
    .
    .
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

The generated Java code will create a file named ClassA.java that looks like:

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB {
.
.
.
}
```